# Файл занят своим же процессом

Tags: c#

Дело вот в чем... Если я открываю файл в своей программе, и пытаюсь этот же файл сохранить, мне выдает ошибку что файл занят другим процессом... И тут mind.exe has stopping working... И теперь как мне высвободить "из под себя" файл? И я использую методы в richtextbox. типа savefile

Comment: Закрыть файл, как минимум. Запускать работу с файлом через `using`, тогда после блока работы с файлом он будет самостоятельно закрыт, а ресурсы с ним связанные очищены.

Comment: @NewView Я забыл добавить, я вообще не использую потоки, я использую встроенный метод в richtextbox.

Comment: Причем тут потоки? Открывая файл для чтения и/или записи - закрывайте его.
Напишите, хотябы, что используете, StreamReader & StreamWriter или File.Open... или что-то другое

Comment: Вот примерчик в документации посмотрите, и попробуйте читать файл подобным образом, [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...Как же стыдно... Я совсем забыл, что я еще открывал потоки, и не закрыл их...